# PHP readline completion strange behavior

Tags: php

I have a project with interactive shell written with php. It supports auto-complete via callback passed to `readline_complete_function` that returns possible commands.

The problem is that if callback returning an empty array the second tap on TAB will result printing the list of files from script's directory which names begins with the token from the line. And i don't know how to disable this behavior.

Comment: are you using `complete` to register your script?

Comment: also put `bash` tag to your post; it would be much faster to get an answer

Comment: if you are using `complete` to register your callback I believe `-f` option could help(http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/complete/)

Comment: @skyboyer, that post is not about bash, i have a php script that behaves like a shell, using `readline`.

Comment: oh, sorry, I misunderstood that

Comment: I was going through manual for readline extension and it looks for me it should interact with current system's shell. So could you try to set appropriate flag to shell disabling filename auto-completion? I guess it may help. Another workaround may be returning array with whitespace as only element.